# Assign user round robin

Tags: laravel, round-robin

I am having a hard time finding a solution. If anyone could help me would be a great help. Let's say I have a user table like:

| id | name | groupid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 1 |
| 2 | brian | 2 |
| 3 | eddy | 1 |
| 4 | mia | 1 |

And when a new meeting is created(after fill up a form), I want to assign them a user like

| id | groupid | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 3 |

How can I assign a user like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help you (and us) if you find a better way to articulate the problem, as well as telling us what you tried in code (in its most basic form). Right now I really can't understand what you are trying to do and why, the explanation is just to vague.

Answer (score 0):

Just create model classes for your entities for the **User**, **Group**, and then write your relationship function in your models. In your case, the relation type is Many To Many because you have many groups assigned to one user or vise-versa.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

And then use the attach on your user objects, group relation to assigning a user to group(s):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

```
$user = User::find(1);
$group = Group::find(1);
$user->group()->attach($group->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count all the meetings by user and then select the one with the lowest count.  However, this would be flawed if you added a new user. They would then be nominated for all meetings until they had caught up.

Keeping track in a round-robin fashion is harder.  You can look at the most recent meeting, get the ID and then get all users (in the group), find the one last used, and then select the next in sequence.

You need to allow for wrapping so that if the last was 4, and there is no next user then it goes back to the first user.

Given an array of user ids as $id, and the most recently used as $current, returns $next for the ID of the user to use next

```
$next = $ids->search($current)+1;

if($next == $ids->count()) {
  $next = 0;
}

$next = $ids[$next];
```